# what is the difference between bloated class and tagged class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, anti-patterns

As i read in `Effective java`

> Bloated class hierarchies can lead to bloated classes containing many
>   methods that differ only in the type of their arguments, as there are
>   no types in the class hierarchy to capture common behaviors.

and in [Link](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/pearce/tdd/smells.htm)

> A bloated class often has many special cases: attributes or behavior
>   valid for some instances but not others. **Often programmers attempt to
>   deal with special cases by introducing type tags**.

and similarity is there between Tagged class to bloated class as  in `Effective java` it is mentioned that:

> a class whose instances come in two or more flavors and contain a tag
>   field indicating the flavor of the instance. instances are burdened
>   with irrelevant fields belonging to other flavors.

so concluding both classes might have **Tag Types/Fields** and *both classes are having so many implementations* (so many features simulated in one class).

i got confused to these terminologies and i want to know that ,what is the difference between these two **Bloated class and Tagged class**??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- A bloated class is bloated (see below).
- A tagged class has one or more tags.
- A tagged class is likely bloated, a bloated class is not necessarily tagged.

"Bloated" is (somewhat) subjective, "tagged" is trivial to identify. "Bloat" can refer to many things; poor separation of concerns, missing encapsulation, differing levels of abstractions, and so on.

"Tagged" is less subjective, because there will be a field that defines the separation of functionality, abstraction, etc.